# Predictive Maintenance Model to Predict Machine Failure

Tags: machine-learning

I was tasked with creating a machine learning algorithm that receives vibration signals and uses them to determine if a machine is going to fail. With that said, I have a small problem.

I am not sure which machine learning algorithm I need to generate this.

Furthermore, any resources that would help me implement said algorithm would be greatly appreciated. I don't have a dataset to work with for the time being so I am currently just drafting ideas.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is asking for external resources, and doesn't show a specific problem that needs to be solved. It also might be opinion-based, and doesn't show any data which would be relevant for the task at hand. Not having a dataset here is also a major issue: sometimes you can get away with extremely simple algorithms like a decision tree just using scikit learn (like a problem I had to solve in grad school), sometimes you'll need something quite more sophisticated. This is a question for another forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the abstract, this is not a terribly complicated problem. First, you'll have to decide/understand what length of time before failure is useful for you circumstances. Do you need to detect failure a week in advance? Or a day in advance? Or an hour in advance? (Of course, you may not be able to predict effectively at any of those time lengths.) Use the past to predict the future; use what you'll have available to predict what you don't know.

This may be a simple problem, may not really require any machine learning at all. BUT, your big problem now isn't methodology. It's lack of data.

You'll need to start recording data and exploring it before you can move forward.